# What is the correct Firebase query for the following case?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my Firebase database structure:
[image: Database]

I want to get 3 children of "Cairo, Egypt" starting from the forth child

I know all about startAt(), endAt(), limitToFirst() and limitToLast() but I am new to Firebase so I am not flexible with enough with it to put it all together to make the correct query for my case ... so any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (in JavaScript):

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users-locale/Cairo, Egypt");
var query = ref.orderByKey().startAt("dummy2").limitToFirst(3);
```

But as Peter said, this structure is really quite bad for almost any type of querying. I highly recommend you get used to NoSQL data modeling by reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) first and also watch [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).